# Map values to viridis colours in r

Tags: r

How do I create a colour scale function in r with a pre-defined scale (like *viridis* from `library("viridis")`?

The question is not how to use it within *ggplot*, but how to build a function I can feed arbitrary values within the specified value domain to and retrieve the according colour strings (rgb, hex or any other output format) from.

`colorRamp` and `colorRampPalette` seem to interpolate only between 2 colours within a given colour space. But how would I go about this with *viridis* for example?

**EDIT:**

Thanks to @sconfluentus' answer I wrote the following function that does what I want (w/o safety checks):

```
library("viridis")

number_vector <- c(0.772, 1.235, 5.78, 8.890, 10.543, 14.702)

map_viridis <- function(vec, num) {

  vector_expanded <-round(vec, 1) * 10 # expand to allow for decimal precision
  vector_exp_range <- max(vector_expanded) - min(vector_expanded)

  colour_vector <- viridis(vector_exp_range + 1) # get vector of colour values for all possible decimals between min and max value
  value_to_colour <- colour_vector[num * 10 - min(vector_expanded) + 1] # retrieve colour value for number

  return(value_to_colour)

}

map_viridis(number_vector, 0.8) # returns "#440154FF"
map_viridis(number_vector, 3.4) # returns "#424086FF"
map_viridis(number_vector, 14.7) # returns "#FDE725FF"
```

Just wondering if there's not a more direct way to achieve this result?

Comment: Did you see the `begin` and `end` arguments?  For example, with `scale_fill_viridis(option = "C", begin = .2, end = .9)`.  You want a function to randomly select those values?

Comment: Thanks @stackTon, my edit above might make the question clearer

Answer (score 12):

Viridis itself is capable creating the values you are looking for provided you use it correctly in your own function and you know how many arbitrary values will be created.

```
viridis(12)
 [1] "#440154FF" "#482173FF" "#433E85FF" "#38598CFF" "#2D708EFF" "#25858EFF" "#1E9B8AFF"
 [8] "#2BB07FFF" "#51C56AFF" "#85D54AFF" "#C2DF23FF" "#FDE725FF"
```

So you could create a function which takes your domain, calculates the length of values in it and then creates a series of colors for each manipulating your data any way you choose. The basis for it would be like this

```
num_vals=length(x) # substitute nrow  for length if you have rows instead of a list
col_pal = viridis(num_vals)
```

As long as the set is ordered then you can simply use `data[1]` and `col_pal[1]` to associate them in pairs..or you could create a list of pairs and colors depending on how you choose to substitute them into your function.

or you could create a ramp with `colorRampPalette` as such

```
map_colors<-colorRampPalette(viridis(12)) # this would create 12 viridis colors
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`library(colourvalues)`](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/colourvalues) (on CRAN 1st October 2018) to assign colours to values. The default palette is viridis.

```
number_vector <- c(0.772, 1.235, 5.78, 8.890, 10.543, 14.702)

colourvalues::colour_values(number_vector)
# [1] "#440154FF" "#470E60FF" "#2E6E8EFF" "#20A486FF" "#44BF70FF" "#FDE725FF"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this does what you want. Most of this was copied from the source of the `viridis` function. It takes in values between 0 and 1 and returns a color a corresponding fraction of the way along the viridis map.

```
get_viridis_color <- function(x, opt="D", begin=0, end=1, reverse=FALSE) {
    x <- x * (end - begin) + begin
    cmap <- viridisLite::viridis.map[viridisLite::viridis.map$opt == opt,]
    if (reverse) cmap <- cmap[rev(seq_len(nrow(cmap))),]
    map_rgbs <- grDevices::rgb(cmap$R, cmap$G, cmap$B)
    ramp <- grDevices::colorRamp(map_rgbs, space="Lab", interpolate="spline")
    out_rgbs <- ramp(x) / 255
    grDevices::rgb(out_rgbs[,1], out_rgbs[,2], out_rgbs[,3])
}
```

Values outside `[0, 1]` are not handled; for some reason this means negative numbers are `#00FF00` and numbers greater than 1 are black. `begin` and `end` work like they do in `viridis()`, but reversing direction of the colormap is a boolean `reverse` argument instead of the 1 or -1 `direction` argument. Different values of `opt` give magma (`"A"`), inferno (`"B"`), and plasma (`"C"`) maps instead of viridis.